# Why do Google 2-factor authentication SMS codes never start with a 0?

Tags: multi-factor, entropy, sms

When you use 2-step authentication to log to your Google Account, you can get an SMS on your mobile-phone with a G-*123456* style code.

I think that I never got a code with a leading zero. Is there a reason for this or is this just an improbable occurrence in the realm of randomness?

Comment: I couldn't find any official documentation on the format they use, but since they prefix the number with a "G-" I would discard the possibility of a leading 0 being ignored in some systems. I am inclined to believe its just luck that you never got a leading zero, I cant remember the codes I've received though, so I cant provide a counter-example

Comment: Probably it's rather "bad" luck. I've received codes starting with zero both from the google auth android app and via sms. If try hard enough you'll probably receive one as well :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a classic implementation choice to help reduce data entry mistakes.

People who are in computer sciences or information security understand the difference between a text string and a series of digits that represents a value.  But people who have been trained in finance, accounting, and other fields have been taught to truncate leading zeros when dealing with numbers.  They are more likely to see a row of digits as a "number that has a value".  For example, if they see "000001", their brain interprets this as the value "one".  When it comes time to enter the code, they recall the value "one" and reflexively type "1".  Numerically it's an equivalent value, but as a text string it's not an exact match.

The system designer has several options to deal with this.

- They can generate codes with leading zeros and allow the few users to make the occasional mistake, forcing them to re-enter it.  That can give the app a reputation that it is difficult to use.
- They can change the input system to match on either text matches or numeric value matches.  This increases the complexity of the user input logic in a critical security area of the code.  The history of security flaws is a list of evidence that shows increases in complexity on processing user input increases the risk of coding errors that lead to vulnerabilities.
- They can generate the code from a restricted set of numbers that never risks causing the user confusion.  This reduces the possible number of valid combinations by about 10%, which the system designer must account for when computing the feasibility of a brute force or random guessing attack.  And by shifting the complexity to the generation section of the code and away from the user input section, programming mistakes may be less likely to create vulnerabilities.

Ultimately, it's a human factors problem for a small fraction of the population.  But security systems are already complex, time-consuming, and frustrating, so any usability issues that increase user frustration are really bad to intentionally keep in a security system (especially one you're trying to market commercially.)

Answer (score 1):

Phone SMS readers have the tendency to interpret text elements to facilitate user navigation. This includes telephone numbers for a quick dial, or add/save to contact.

The use of a `G-[1-9][0-9]{5}` pattern is therefore very likely to be a way to avoid that common behaviour so that it does not prevent other action like copy or trigger inappropriate action like call or save to contact.

Comment: How does not having a leading zero make misinterpretation less likely?

Comment: Many countries does have phone numbers that all begins by a 0 (mostly in Europe).

Comment: Yes. But many countries also have phone numbers that begin with a 1 through 9. They protect against those being misinterpreted as a phone number by prefixing the code with the `G-`. Why doesn't that also work for numbers beginning with 0?

Comment: Because devs are stupid I guess. I don't count the number of time where my phone ever interpreted a number or a part of a number, as a phone number just because there was a 0 followed by nine digits.

Comment: Anyway the question is probably opinion based, since we can't know for sure why they did it.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the algorithm is based closely on the one they use for Google Authenticator, TOTP (if not the exact same given the similar usage context) and the algorithm used by that was tailored to ensure the result was always 6 digits, based on several much larger calculations. I dont know enough about the actual HMAC process to say for sure that a 0 couldn't end up in the output but it is apparently unlikely.  Here is a fairly detailed breakdown: https://garbagecollected.org/2014/09/14/how-google-authenticator-works/

Comment: I've seen leading zeroes in Google auth app